Regex to Ignore parts in a batches of string
I was wondering if its possible to build a regex for this situation. Some context, I am working with patch(diff) files to find the difference between some ASCII file types and I want to match the string section as shown here.
Note: Comments in these "ASCII file types" are the ones after "!"
Should Match
Example 1.
- Content AAAA ! Comment which can be ignored
- Content BBBB ! Comment which can be ignored
- Content CCCC ! Comment which can be ignored
+ Content AAAA ! Comment which can be ignored even if it is different
+ Content BBBB ! Comment which can be ignored even if it is different
+ Content CCCC ! Comment which can be ignored even if it is different

Example 2.
- Exact same content ! Comment which can be ignored
+ Exact same content ! Comment which can be ignored even if it is different

So if the content section with (+) and (-) are same if the comments are ignored.
Should not match
This should not match as its different content,
Example 3.
- Content AAAA ! Comment which can be ignored
- Content BBBB ! Comment which can be ignored
- Content CCCC ! Comment which can be ignored
+ Content 1111 ! Comment which can be ignored even if it is different
+ Content 2222 ! Comment which can be ignored even if it is different
+ Content 3333 ! Comment which can be ignored even if it is different

For single lines differences (As shown in Example 2), I have a working Regex as shown here
-(.+)!.*\r?\n\+\1.+
but I cannot create one for multiline strings as shown in Example 1.

Should Match - what should match with what?

A regex matching the entire block. For example, this is my working version for a single line https://regex101.com/r/yTAkWn/1.
I want to create a regex which will match as shown here: https://regex101.com/r/45EMJ4/1 and gives me 3 matches

What should I add additionally/how should I have phrased the question differently?. Please let me know.

Sounds like you need a regex that looks in both directions to also match the block that has your "same content" behind. If this is the case, I think it will be quite a challenge and you'd need variable length lookbehind (available e.g. in JS regex or .NET). Something like (?:(?:^-([^!]+)(?:!.*)?\n(?=[\S\s]*?^\+\1(?:!|$)))+|(?:^\+([^!]+)(?:!.*)?(?:\n|$)(?<=^-\2(?:!|$)[\S\s]*\n.*))+)+ (certainly inefficient and hard to maintain) try the different versions in regex101...

This is perfect. Thank you so much.

Can you add this as an answer so that I can mark it as an answer. This works very well, but I am having trouble understanding how it works.

Should the order of - Content AAAA - Content BBBB - Content CCCC come in the same order in the part that starts with the + signs? If not, perhaps ^-([^\n!]*!).*(?=(?:\n-.*)*(?:\n\+.*)*\n\+\1) See https://regex101.com/r/4ZlZTj/1

@Amazonian_panda Great that helped! I don't have the time to explain it right now. It uses capturing and lookarounds. If it solved your question you might want to answer yourself (you're welcome to use the regex that I provided) or wait for another answer! I can't see why they downvote so much here.

The pattern I provided consists of two parts ^-([^!]+)(?:!.*)?\n(?=[\S\s]*?^\+\1(?:!|$)) for each line with a duplicate ahead OR ^\+([^!]+)(?:!.*)?(?:\n|$)(?<=^-\1(?:!|$)[\S\s]*\n.*) for each line with duplicate behind (changed second group to \1 for showcase). Because it sounded that you want to match blocks consisting of contiguous such lines, both patterns are alternated inside a (?: non-capturing group ) and repeated one or more times.

Oops, I used too many groups in my first pattern, it can be shortened to: (?:^-([^!]+)(?:!.*)?\n(?=[\S\s]*?^\+\1(?:!|$))|^\+([^!]+)(?:!.*)?(?:\n|$)(?<=^-\2(?:!|$)[\S\s]*\n.*))+ (which doesn't make it much more efficient).

Thanks, that really helped. The shortened Regex worked beautifully for my use case as well. I'll add your solution as an answer and set it as "Solved".

Don't think of it as a block to be matched, go line by line. Once you match content - AAAA, you'll need to look ahead to find any instance of + AAAA and then restore your pointer to to the same for - BBBB. The lookahead in regex is made for that purpose. So, rewriting your regex slightly,
/^-(.+?)(!.*?)?$(?=.*?^\+\1)

I also made the comment section optional.  You will need to set the single-line flag (/s) so that dot (.)  matches newline characters, and the multiline flag (/m) so that up-arrow & dollar sign anchors match line boundaries as well as string boundaries.
Note that this can fail if you have multiple instances of the same content in your file.
Here is a screenshot of this regex in Regex101:

